# Flattening multiple lists of lists with single function or line

Tags: python

i have multiple lists of lists and i want to flatten these lists. I found a way how to flatten each individual list but cant figure out a way to flatten all of them in a single function or line.

Here is a code example

```
first = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
second = [[3,5,6], [0,3,4]]
third = [[2,5,0], [1,2,9]]

flat_first = [item for sublist in first for item in sublist]
flat_second = [item for sublist in second for item in sublist]
flat_third = [item for sublist in third for item in sublist]
```

Now i want to do the same as before but cleaner and in one line or function call

I've tried but I can see why the code is wrong but cant wrap my head around a correct solution:

```
def flatten(lst):
    lst = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
    return lst

for item in lists:
    item = flatten(item)
```

Ideal output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[3,5,6,0,3,4]
[2,5,0,1,2,9]
```